# How to catch and parse IOException error code in Java?

Tags: java

```
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(file.getAbsolutePath());
    processBuilder.directory(file.getParentFile());

    try {
        processBuilder.start();
        System.exit(0);
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**When I use C://:**

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\UsefulTul": CreateProcess error=5, 存取被拒。

**When i use C://sdfsdsfjsdi:**

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "c:\sdfsdsfjsdi
" (in directory "c:\"): CreateProcess error=2, 系統找不到指定的檔案。

How to catch the `error=<code>` in Java

Comment: What about using `getMessage()` on the exception object?

Comment: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\UsefulTul": CreateProcess error=5, 存取被拒。

Comment: isnt it just a code not a message?

Comment: Parse the error message, maybe use a regex for that. Please [edit] your question to include the problem on how to get his value from the string.

Comment: The message of a `Throwable` can be accessed by `getMessage()`. To find the error code of this particular message you may for example use a regex (see `Pattern` class), or find `error=` substring (`String::indexOf`) and read the number after that substring.

Comment: How to use regex to get it? Hard...

Comment: @夏特稀, have added a sample code to get `error=<code>` using RegEx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to get the expected value from the message.

```java
try {
    processBuilder.start();
    System.exit(0);
} catch(IOException ex) {
    String msg = ex.getMessage();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*(error=.*),.*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ex.getMessage());
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Result: " + matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
Result: error=2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Note**: In my run, the `error=2` was the message given by `ex.getMessage()`. It might be different in your case.